# Read/Write permission on subfolders with mount.cifs

Tags: mount, cifs

I have a problem when trying to mount a specific folder from a remote disk in the /media folder.

The folder is mounted correctly with the proper permissions at its root, but I can't get a rw access to all the subdirectories, everything is in read-only.

I'm using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,password=mypassword,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777, //serveripaddress/commun /media/commun
```

How can I simply specify that the rw permission should be applied in a recursive way?

I'm using Debian 9, Linux 4.9.0-4

Comment: The CIFS server needs to allow writes too.  Just mounting it `rw` is not enough.

Comment: @SatōKatsura but according with `man mount.cifs` the `rw` is for _read write_ ... can you expand your comment?

Comment: @ManuelJordan `rw` _allows_ you to (try to) do writes on the mounted filesystem, it doesn't _guarantee_ the writes will succeed.  Example: if you mount a CD as `rw` you still wouldn't be able to write on it.  The actual writes on the mounted filesystem can fail for a variety of reasons, f.i. because the filesystem itself is read-only.  Or because the Samba process doesn't have proper permissions to write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is now solved. I have added a uid option to the command to specify my linux log name and I have mounted the remote folder to /mnt/commun instead of /media/commun (not sure which one is really helping).

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=windowsname,password=mypassword,iud=linuxname,rw //serveripaddress/commun /mnt/commun
```

Comment: should be `uid` and **not** _iud_, seems mandatory use `gid` too